# How to view the worldwide most subscribed channels in YouTube?

Tags: youtube

When I access [YouTube's most subscribed channels](http://www.youtube.com/channels?s=ms&t=a&g=0&c=0&p=1), I only see the most subscribed channels by the users of my country (Brazil). I want to see the worldwide most subscribed channels, or at least US most subscribed channels. I think YouTube is (reverse) geocoding my IP or getting it from my "User Agent", because in my YouTube profile I set the country to "United States" but this setting is ignored. My browser (Chrome) is also set to accept pages only in English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the youtube homepage, and then scroll down to the bottom. Click on the location link (in your case it will say Location: Brazil) and then from the menu that appears choose Worldwide: All. Go back to the most subscribed channels page and... voila!